# Firebase Analytics upload delay

Tags: android, firebase-analytics

Is there any way to increase Firebase Analytics upload rate for logged events on android? Currently it uploads them every hour and it is too slow for testing purposes.

I found references to following keys (with hardcoded defaults) in jars, but no idea how to change them.

- "measurement.upload.backoff_period", 43200000L
- "measurement.upload.window_interval", 3600000L
- "measurement.upload.interval", 3600000L

Comment: Yapaxi, what problem you are trying to solve with the shorter upload rate? Is it only needed to debug your Firebase Analytics setup?

Comment: No, actualy I am trying to push enough data to Analytics to check tools and their behaviour. But it takes to long: hour to upload, 3+ hours to analytics and ?? hours to BigQuery. For debug purposes verbose logging is quite helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is currently no way to manually override these settings.  However, we recognize the need to see your reporting more quickly and we hope to address this need soon.

In the meantime, you can enable verbose debug output to verify that your events are indeed being logged and uploaded.  Issue the following commands and then run your app and log events :

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC
```

Hope this helps,

Steve Ganem

Product Manager, Firebase Analytics

Comment: how about now @SteveGanem? :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a "way" to load test data a bit faster: data wipe (emulator) forces app to use "initial delay", which is 15 seconds only.

Comment: Nice find! This works inded to force the uploads, but unfortunatelly will not make the data visible on Firebase console as the website probably generates the reports regularly at set times.

Answer (score 0):

No, the application can not control the upload cadence for Firebase Analytics. On Google Play devices the uploading is done by Google Play Services and there is no application code involved in the process. On non Google Play devices the uploading is done from the application process. Accelerated uploading is common request and and it might be supported in future release.

Comment: Correct me if am wrong: on Google Play devices, if user closes application after 10 minutes, logs will be anyway pushed to Firebase within a hour, or later, if internet connection is down. On non Google Play devices, if user closes application after 10 minutes, then events are lost.
What is Google Play device then? Device that can run Google Play services or Android-like only?