# Firebase with BigQuery

Tags: android, firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I have a really hard time understanding how to register custom event and then visualize them in BigQuery. Since the Google IO conference, I can't find anything detailed about the process other than those conference video that are really basic and broad...

How can I register a custom data in a Firebase Event and then see it in BigQuery?

```
    Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();
    bundle2.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_CATEGORY, "tab_open");
    bundle2.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "profil");
    mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle2);
```

Or another example:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("email", email);
params.putString("name", name);
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("profil", params);
```

How to access those value inside firebase? Also, I did a lot of bad test which flood my Firebase with wrong data, can I erase an event type ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You’re logging the events correctly, but it takes about 5 hours for events to show up in your Firebase Dashboard from the time they occur (more details from the Firebase Analytics PM in this answer: [Firebase Analytics upload delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37416122/firebase-analytics-upload-delay))

Here’s an example query to find the number of times each custom event has occurred:

```
SELECT event_dim.name, COUNT(event_dim.name) as event_count FROM [your_dataset.your_table]
GROUP BY event_dim.name
ORDER BY event_count DESC
```

You can’t delete rows from a BigQuery table, but since a new table is created every day, you can just stop logging an event and filter your results starting from a specific date. Alternatively, you could reprocess the tables and remove the old events.