# Android Firebase Analytics events dont display on console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have integrated firebase analytics in My android project. I am trying to capture screen visit events like.

```
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_CATEGORY, "Custom  screen");
    params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME,"Custom screen name");
    mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.VIEW_ITEM, params);
```

I have also tried from the google sample project with this code

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "1");
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "test name");
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "image");
    mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
```

My debug logs are showing that events are successfully posted.

```
09-19 14:22:15.364 I/FA      ( 3313): App measurement is starting up, version: 9452
09-19 14:22:15.364 I/FA      ( 3313): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
09-19 14:22:15.364 D/FA      ( 3313): Debug logging enabled
09-19 14:22:15.365 D/FA      ( 3313): AppMeasurement singleton hash: 233567450
09-19 14:22:15.383 V/FA      ( 3313): Collection enabled
09-19 14:22:15.383 V/FA      ( 3313): App package, google app id: com.prabhu.test, 1:64059382301:android:4262dc7062227fc8
09-19 14:22:15.393 V/FA      ( 3313): Registered activity lifecycle callback
09-19 14:22:15.403 V/FA      ( 3313): Using measurement service
09-19 14:22:15.404 V/FA      ( 3313): Connecting to remote service
09-19 14:22:15.433 V/FA      ( 3313): onActivityCreated
09-19 14:22:15.529 I/FA      ( 3313): Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
09-19 14:22:15.529 D/FA      ( 3313): Logging event (FE): select_content, Bundle[{item_name=test name, _o=app, content_type=image, item_id=1}]
09-19 14:22:15.530 V/FA      ( 3313): Using measurement service
09-19 14:22:15.530 V/FA      ( 3313): Connection attempt already in progress
09-19 14:22:15.532 D/FA      ( 3313): Logging event (FE): view_item, Bundle[{item_name=Custom screen name, _o=app, item_category=Custom  screen}]
09-19 14:22:15.532 V/FA      ( 3313): Using measurement service
09-19 14:22:15.532 V/FA      ( 3313): Connection attempt already in progress
09-19 14:22:15.532 V/FA      ( 3313): Activity resumed, time: 273496560
09-19 14:22:15.698 D/FA      ( 3313): Connected to remote service
09-19 14:22:15.698 V/FA      ( 3313): Processing queued up service tasks: 3
09-19 14:22:15.751 V/FA-SVC  (10602): Logging event: origin=app,name=select_content,params=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=168]
09-19 14:22:15.766 V/FA-SVC  (10602): Saving event, name, data size: select_content, 79
09-19 14:22:15.768 V/FA-SVC  (10602): Event recorded: Event{appId='com.prabhu.test', name='select_content', params=Bundle[{item_name=test name, _o=app, content_type=image, item_id=1}]}
09-19 14:22:16.168 V/FA-SVC  (10602): Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 2557230
09-19 14:22:16.171 V/FA-SVC  (10602): Background event processing time, ms: 423
09-19 14:22:16.171 V/FA-SVC  (10602): Logging event: origin=app,name=view_item,params=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=176]
09-19 14:22:16.175 V/FA-SVC  (10602): Saving event, name, data size: view_item, 84
09-19 14:22:16.175 V/FA-SVC  (10602): Event recorded: Event{appId='com.prabhu.test', name='view_item', params=Bundle[{item_name=Custom screen name, _o=app, item_category=Custom  screen}]}
09-19 14:22:16.212 V/FA-SVC  (10602): Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 2557187
09-19 14:22:16.215 V/FA-SVC  (10602): Background event processing time, ms: 44
09-19 14:22:20.723 V/FA      ( 3313): Inactivity, disconnecting from AppMeasurementService
09-19 14:22:22.384 V/FA      ( 3313): Activity paused, time: 273503415
09-19 14:22:23.515 V/FA      ( 3313): onActivityCreated
09-19 14:22:23.531 D/FA      ( 3313): Logging event (FE): select_content, Bundle[{item_name=test name, _o=app, content_type=image, item_id=1}]
09-19 14:22:23.531 V/FA      ( 3313): Using measurement service
09-19 14:22:23.531 V/FA      ( 3313): Connecting to remote service
09-19 14:22:23.539 D/FA      ( 3313): Logging event (FE): view_item, Bundle[{item_name=Custom screen name, _o=app, item_category=Custom  screen}]
09-19 14:22:23.539 V/FA      ( 3313): Using measurement service
09-19 14:22:23.539 V/FA      ( 3313): Connection attempt already in progress
09-19 14:22:23.539 V/FA      ( 3313): Activity resumed, time: 273504562
09-19 14:22:23.594 D/FA      ( 3313): Connected to remote service
09-19 14:22:23.594 V/FA      ( 3313): Processing queued up service tasks: 2
09-19 14:22:23.602 V/FA-SVC  (10602): Saving event, name, data size: select_content, 79
09-19 14:22:23.603 V/FA-SVC  (10602): Event recorded: Event{appId='com.prabhu.test', name='select_content', params=Bundle[{item_name=test name, _o=app, content_type=image, item_id=1}]}
09-19 14:22:23.630 V/FA-SVC  (10602): Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 2549768
09-19 14:22:23.632 V/FA-SVC  (10602): Background event processing time, ms: 35
09-19 14:22:23.632 V/FA-SVC  (10602): Logging event: origin=app,name=view_item,params=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=176]
09-19 14:22:23.636 V/FA-SVC  (10602): Saving event, name, data size: view_item, 84
09-19 14:22:23.636 V/FA-SVC  (10602): Event recorded: Event{appId='com.prabhu.test', name='view_item', params=Bundle[{item_name=Custom screen name, _o=app, item_category=Custom  screen}]}
09-19 14:22:23.648 V/FA-SVC  (10602): Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 2549750
09-19 14:22:23.651 V/FA-SVC  (10602): Background event processing time, ms: 18
09-19 14:22:26.687 V/FA      ( 3313): Session started, time: 273507718
09-19 14:22:26.699 D/FA      ( 3313): Logging event (FE): _s, Bundle[{_o=auto}]
09-19 14:22:26.709 V/FA-SVC  (10602): Logging event: origin=auto,name=_s,params=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=36]
09-19 14:22:26.738 V/FA-SVC  (10602): Saving event, name, data size: _s, 19
09-19 14:22:26.739 V/FA-SVC  (10602): Event recorded: Event{appId='com.prabhu.test', name='_s', params=Bundle[{_o=auto}]}
09-19 14:22:26.754 V/FA-SVC  (10602): Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 2546644
09-19 14:22:26.757 V/FA-SVC  (10602): Background event processing time, ms: 48
09-19 14:22:31.717 V/FA      ( 3313): Inactivity, disconnecting from AppMeasurementService
09-19 14:24:23.422 V/FA      ( 3313): Activity paused, time: 273624439
09-19 14:24:24.423 D/FA      ( 3313): Application backgrounded. Logging engagement
09-19 14:24:24.427 D/FA      ( 3313): Logging event (FE): _e, Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=126732}]
09-19 14:24:24.427 V/FA      ( 3313): Using measurement service
09-19 14:24:24.428 V/FA      ( 3313): Connecting to remote service
09-19 14:24:24.444 D/FA      ( 3313): Connected to remote service
09-19 14:24:24.444 V/FA      ( 3313): Processing queued up service tasks: 1
09-19 14:24:24.450 V/FA-SVC  (10602): Logging event: origin=auto,name=_e,params=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=60]
09-19 14:24:24.480 V/FA-SVC  (10602): Saving event, name, data size: _e, 30
09-19 14:24:24.481 V/FA-SVC  (10602): Event recorded: Event{appId='com.prabhu.test', name='_e', params=Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=126732}]}
09-19 14:24:24.500 V/FA-SVC  (10602): Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 2428898
09-19 14:24:24.505 V/FA-SVC  (10602): Background event processing time, ms: 56
09-19 14:24:29.455 V/FA      ( 3313): Inactivity, disconnecting from AppMeasurementService
```

But , In my firebase analytics console events are not shown.

Please help me whats wrong with me?
FYI, For the same Google Firebase Analytics Project, events are shown from IOS app.

Comment: it's take 24 hours to show on console .

Comment: I know it. For other project I have been waiting from 36 hours

Comment: For first time it's take more time to log the event .

Answer (score 6):

Look at the log:

```
09-19 14:22:16.168 V/FA-SVC  (10602): Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 2557230
```

`2557230 ms` means `42 min 37 sec`

Then also they seem to generate the reports regularly but not realtime.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events

> You can view aggregrated statistics about your events in the Firebase
>   console dashboards. These dashboards update periodically throughout
>   the day. For immediate testing, use the logcat output as described in
>   the previous section.

**UPDATE**:

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37424731/308836) from Steve Ganem, Product Manager for Firebase Analytics:

> There is currently no way to manually override these settings.
>   However, we recognize the need to see your reporting more quickly and
>   we hope to address this need soon.

BUT, on the same thread Yoxi found a way to [force initial upload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37431042/308836) sooner by clearing application data. I just did myself and I could see the initial upload. But that doesn't seem to make the data visible in the Firebase console any sooner.

```
11-04 14:46:14.112 V/FA      (24746): Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 9028
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run setprop `adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app <package name>`

for example `adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.google.android.play.games`

If you run this, firebase analytics events are uploaded in near real-time.

check this for more details

https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview